# Changing Image and Text Dynamically Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, text

Currently I have a translation script built into my website.

My problem is activating it and also changing the image and text to the selected language.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="images/flag/United-Kingdom.png" alt=""> English <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/flag/Germany.png" alt=""> Deutsch</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/flag/France.png" alt=""> Français</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/flag/Spain.png" alt=""> Español</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/flag/Nederlands.png" alt=""> Nederlands</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

How do I get it to change the current language selection image to the one they have selected?

If you need more info I'll be happy to give it.

Comment: If you don't know how the translation script works, what makes you think we do, when we haven't seen it, or know what translation script you're talking about ?

Comment: `myElement.src = 'newimage.png'` ? We need to see what your main script does, HTML does not show much.

Comment: @adeneo This isn't about the translation script. This is about how to dynmically change the image and text when an option is selected :D

Comment: Will clearly need more details to understand the problem and give suggestion. But if it is only about changing the selected value, you will have register a click on list item and use jquery to change the image and text in button based on clicked option. You will also need to change the dropdown list by removing the clicked language and adding the previously selected language so that it comes in dropdown now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the image source and text of the clicked item and replace the button content with it

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html( $(this).html() + '<span class="fa fa-bars"></span>');    
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/e3ajz1jy/2)

---

Or without jQuery

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeDefault(this)"><img src="images/flag/Germany.png" alt="" > Deutsch</a>
```

JS

```
function changeDefault(item) {    
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0]
    button.innerHTML = item.innerHTML + '<span class="fa fa-bars"></span>';
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/e3ajz1jy/1/)

Comment: That awesome. Works like a charm. Now my question for this is, how do I change the script to only work on that specific dropdown?

Comment: Add an unique identifier / ID to the `.dropdown`  element like so http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/e3ajz1jy/3/